# How to turn a column of ints into one array in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I currently have a table with one column and 400 rows; each row has an integer. How can I create an int array with all of these integers that preserves order?

I am using postgreSQL-9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select array_agg(int_column order by some_column) as int_array_column
from the_table;
```

Where `some_column` is the column that defines the "order" of the integer values. Rows in relational database do not have "an order", so your request "that preserves order" only makes sense if you have a column that defines that sort order that you try to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT array_agg(column_name ORDER by sort_column_name) AS ints
FROM table
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content. They also don't explain why they should "try this", and we make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge. Posting a block of code with no other information isn't sharing knowledge - it's just offering copy/paste code.